# Is there a way to automatically accept a license when installing a NuGet package?

Tags: licensing, nuget

I created a NuGet package of my own that has a dependency on another 3rd party NuGet package.  This 3rd party package requires that you accept the license.  My NuGet package is used internally at work and will only be published to our internal feed.  We have prebuild steps in our projects to automatically install/update references to my package when a new one exists.  However, `nuget [install|update]` fails because it is "Unable to resolve dependency" to the 3rd party license.  Is there a way to have the license automatically accepted either thru the command line or as an attribute in the nuspec ?

Comment: If it says unable to resolve dependency why do you think that's because of a license acceptance problem? Are you using Visual Studio or NuGet.exe?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem ended up being with the way we were calling install and update. We passed in the source param which only contained our internal server.